# Plot filling planes with data

Tags: plotting

This is an image, each set of data has a face fill

[image]

So now I have a set of data, and I've drawn part of it using `ListLinePlot3D`

```mathematica
data1 = {{2.1, 2.9, 2.8, 1.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2, 
    2.7, 1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3}, {2.4, 1.0, 
    2.6, 2.4, 1.0, 2.6, 2.4}};
data2 = {{2.1, 2.9, 2.8, 1.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2, 
     2.7, 1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3}, {2.4, 1.0, 
     2.6, 2.4, 1.0, 2.6, 2.4}} + RandomReal[];

listPlt1 = ListLinePlot3D[data1,
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium},
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue], Directive[Green], Directive[Purple],
      Directive[Black]}
   ];
listPlt2 = ListLinePlot3D[data2,
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}
   ];

Show[listPlt1, listPlt2,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I try to use the `Filling` function,But I found it impossible to achieve this effect

Here is a diagram I drew in `PowerPoint`

How do I achieve this effect in Wolfram

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manually draw planes where you need them:

```
Show[
  listPlt1, listPlt2,
  Graphics3D[{
    Opacity[0.3],
    MapThread[
      {#1, InfinitePlane[{{0, #2, 0},{0, #2, 10},{10, #2, 10}}]}&,
      {{Red, Blue, Green, Black}, Range[4]}
    ]
  }], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: same plot as OP, but with four semi transparent planes]

Answer (score 7):

An alternative way to draw the desired planes:

```
Show[listPlt1, listPlt2,
 Graphics3D @
  MapIndexed[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[.2], #, Hyperplane[{0, 1, 0}, #2[[1]]]} &] @
   {Blue, Green, Purple, Black},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I learn too much!